# Отключить (но не скрыть) ссылки, в зависимости от роли пользователя WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Есть сайт на WordPress. Есть 5 ролей пользователей, например: `kurs1` `kurs2` `kurs3` `kurs4` `kurs5`. И есть ссылки (5 блоков) на странице. Можно ли сделать, что бы пользователи видели все 5 блоков, но могли войти только в тот блок, который соответствует роли пользователя?

```css
.kyrsi {
  width: 69px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #c1c1c1;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="kyrsi" href="/kurs1">Курс 1</a>
  <a class="kyrsi" href="/kurs2">Курс 2</a>
  <a class="kyrsi" href="/kurs3">Курс 3</a>
  <a class="kyrsi" href="/kurs4">Курс 4</a>
  <a class="kyrsi" href="/kurs5">Курс 5</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Да обрабатывайте отдельно click и уберите ссылку. Что вам мешает генерировать мтраницу с учетом прав

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать функцию WordPress [current_user_can()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/current_user_can) при генерации страницы. Пример:

```php
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
        <?php if ( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) { ?>
            <a class="kyrsi" href="/kurs1">Курс 1</a>
        <?php } else { ?>
            Курс 1
        <?php } ?>
    </li>
    <li>
        <?php if ( current_user_can( 'editor' ) ) { ?>
            <a class="kyrsi" href="/kurs2">Курс 2</a>
        <?php } else { ?>
            Курс 2
        <?php } ?>
    </li>
    <li>Курс 2</li>
    <li>Курс 3</li>
    <li>Курс 4</li>
    <li>Курс 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```